# Getting a value from a string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to match one or more keywords within a string (str), but I have no luck. My method below is trying to match all keys when I only needed to match any (one or more).

```
@str = "g stands for girl and b is for boy"

def key1
 %w[a, b, c, d, f, g]
end    

def result
 if @str.include?( key1 )
  puts "happy days"
 else
  puts "bad days"
 end
end

puts result # => bad days
```

How to make it show "happy days"?

PS: I have no idea what to name this title to. Maybe a mod could rename it?

Comment: It's not clear what you want here, do you want to check if the string in  `@str` has any of the letters in `key1`?

Comment: @victorkohl Yes. Sorry if I can't structure my question precisely.

Comment: maybe you should refactor your case from a str to a boolean, or why are you exactly do this "thing" within a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking if your string includes the Array:  `["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g"]`

What I think you're trying to ask is this:  are there any elements in the array that also exist in the string?  This is a good use case for [Enumerable#any](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) like this:

```
[2] pry(main)> @str = "g stands for girl and b is for boy"
=> "g stands for girl and b is for boy"
[3] key1 = %w[a b c d f g]
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g"]
[4] pry(main)> key1.any? { |letter| @str.include?(letter) }
=> true
```

So to refactor your code, it might look like this:

```
@str = "g stands for girl and b is for boy"

def key1
 %w[a b c d f g]
end    

def result
 if key1.any? { |letter| @str.include?(letter) }
  puts "happy days"
 else
  puts "bad days"
 end
end
```

Something to note, with %w you don't need to use commas, you can simply separate the letters by a space (as outlined above).

Comment: Sir you are the best! This is what I was looking for but I dont know how to get the .any? to work! Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's what I have. You are the best!

Comment: Thanks Cary, I cleaned that up.

Comment: Me == dog-with-bone. The commas are not optional, because one obtains an incorrect result if they are included.

Comment: I think we confused each other, in the future a suggested edit is probably preferred over the back and forth on the comments.  I usually agree with what your statements are, I think it would give me a view into your exact point.

Answer (score 1):

I can't clearly understand your question, but I suspect you are looking for following:

```
key1.find { |k| @str.include? k }
```

Comment: You seem to understand it well enough. You could use `index` as instead of `find`, but `find` reads better, but still doesn't read as well as `any?`, imo.

Comment: as bonus you get value as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression:

```
MAGIC_CHARS = %w[a b c d f g]
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g"]

def result(str)
  (str =~ /#{MAGIC_CHARS.join('|')}/) ? "happy days" : "bad days"
end

result("g stands for girl and b is for boy")
  #=> "happy days" 
result("nothin' here")
  #=> "bad days"
```

Note:

```
/#{MAGIC_CHARS.join('|')}/
  #=> /a|b|c|d|f|g/
```

You could instead write:

```
Regexp.union(MAGIC_CHARS.map { |c| /c/ })
  #=> /(?-mix:c)|(?-mix:c)|(?-mix:c)|(?-mix:c)|(?-mix:c)|(?-mix:c)/
```

or

```
/[#{MAGIC_CHARS.join('')}]/
  #=> /[abcdfg]/
```

Another way:

```
def result(str)
  (str.chars & MAGIC_CHARS).any? ? "happy days" : "bad days"
end

result("g stands for girl and b is for boy")
  #=> "happy days" 
result("nothin' here")
  #=> "bad days"
```